# Inserting into related tables

Tags: postgresql, insert, cte, auto-increment

I have a database setup with the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE siteInfo (
    siteID             SERIAL  NOT NULL,
    siteName           TEXT    NOT NULL,
    siteHost           TEXT    NOT NULL,
    notes              TEXT    NOT NULL,
    allowableCountries TEXT    NOT NULL,
    displayChance      INT     NOT NULL,
    imagePath          TEXT    NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (siteID)
);

CREATE TABLE siteLinks (
    siteID             SERIAL  NOT NULL,
    URL                TEXT    NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (siteID) REFERENCES siteInfo(siteID) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE siteDemographicLinks (
    siteID             SERIAL  NOT NULL,
    URL                TEXT    NOT NULL,
    country            TEXT    NOT NULL,
    chance             INT     NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (siteID) REFERENCES siteInfo(siteID) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE linkVisits (
    siteID             SERIAL  NOT NULL,
    rawVisit           BIGINT  NOT NULL,
    redirects          BIGINT  NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (siteID) REFERENCES siteInfo(siteID) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Data from my form is in the following format:

```
array(7) {
["siteName"]=>string(9) "Site Name"
["siteHost"]=>string(9) "SIte Host"
["notes"]=>string(5) "Notes"
["links"]=>array(2) {[0]=>string(6) "Link 1" [1]=>string(6) "Link 2"}
["countries"]=>string(4) "None"
["displayChance"]=>string(2) "15"
["extraLink"]=>array(2) {
   [0]=>array(3) {
      ["url"]=>string(7) "dSite 1"
      ["countries"]=>string(4) "NONE"
      ["chance"]=>string(2) "11"
      }
   [1]=>array(3) {
      ["url"]=>string(6) "dSite2"
      ["countries"]=>string(4) "None"
      ["chance"]=>string(2) "13"
      }
   }
}
```

How would I go abound inserting data into the many type tables so they reference tuples inserted into the one type table?

I have this query constructed:

```
INSERT INTO siteInfo (siteName, siteHost, notes, allowableCountries, displayChance, imagePath)
VALUES ('Sample', 'sample.com', 'note', 'NONE', '50', '../var');
```

I would then need to insert data into the `siteLinks` table, which is related to the entry already in the `siteInfo` table.

```
INSERT INTO siteLinks (siteID, URL)
VALUES ((SELECT siteid FROM siteinfo WHERE sitename='Sample'), 'test');
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 7):

Chain your insert with [data-modifying CTEs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING):

```
WITH ins0 AS (
   INSERT INTO siteInfo (siteName, siteHost, notes, ... )
   VALUES ('Sample', 'sample.com', 'note', ... );
   RETURNING siteid
   )
INSERT INTO siteLinks (siteID, URL)
SELECT siteid, 'test'
FROM   ins0;
```

Or use [`lastval()` or `currval()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-sequence.html):

```
BEGIN;

INSERT INTO siteInfo (siteName, siteHost, notes, ... )
VALUES ('Sample', 'sample.com', 'note', ... );

INSERT INTO siteLinks (siteID, URL)
VALUES (lastval(), 'test');

COMMIT;
```

Related:

- [Reference value of serial column in another column during same INSERT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12433446/939860)
- [PostgreSQL multi INSERT…RETURNING with multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22775268/939860)