# INSERT rows in two tables preserving connection to a third table

Tags: postgresql, insert, sequence

I'm stuck with a query for which I can't seem to find and elegant solution without looping.

Relevant bits of the schema:

```
CREATE TABLE sites (
  site_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  ...
);

CREATE TABLE properties (
  property_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  property_def_id INT NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (property_def_id) REFERENCES property_def(property_def_id)
);

CREATE TABLE site_properties (
  property_id INT NOT NULL,
  site_id INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (property_id, site_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (property_id) REFERENCES properties(property_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (site_id) REFERENCES sites(site_id)
);
```

The task:
Insert one new, distinct property in table `properties` for each row in table `sites` and also insert a row in `site_properties` to store  the relation between both.

Desired behaviour:
For each `site_id` (as `my_site_id`) in sites:

```
INSERT INTO properties (property_def_id)
VALUES (1)  
RETURNING property_id INTO my_prop_id;

INSERT INTO site_properties (property_id, site_id)
VALUES (my_prop_id, my_site_id);
```

At the end, I would have in the `site_properties` table each "new" property having being assigned only to one site (i.e. no cross-joins)

I feel it should be possible to do this in one query, but I couldn't figure out how for the love of me. I have tried CTEs but I ended up being stuck with a list of property_id's, a list of sites and no way to join between the two.

What am I missing?

Comment: Where do the values for `properties.property_def_id` come from?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It's an input to the stored procedure which does this operation and you can assume it's a "valid" value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Problem

Expressions in the `RETURNING` clause of an `INSERT` can only involve columns from inserted rows, **not** columns from additional tables joined in. That makes it hard to associate each newly inserted row in the table `properties` to *one* particular `sites.site_id`.

[The manual on `INSERT`:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html)

> The optional `RETURNING` clause causes `INSERT` to compute and return
> value(s) based on **each row actually inserted** (or updated, if an
> `ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE` clause was used). This is primarily useful for
> obtaining values that were supplied by defaults, **such as a serial
> sequence number**. However, any **expression using the table's
> columns** is allowed.

Bold emphasis mine.

#### Solution

Use [**`nextval()`** from the family of sequence functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-sequence.html) to solve this cheaply and elegantly. Used to be the canonical way before `RETURNING` was introduced for `INSERT` with Postgres 8.2, and still works.

Use [`pg_get_serial_sequence()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-CATALOG-TABLE) to get the name of the underlying sequence for the `serial` column:

```
WITH site_prop AS (
   SELECT site_id
        , nextval(pg_get_serial_sequence('properties', 'property_id')) AS prop_id
   FROM   sites
   )
, props AS (
   INSERT INTO properties (property_id, property_def_id)
   SELECT prop_id, 1
   FROM   site_prop
   )
INSERT INTO site_properties (site_id, property_id)
SELECT site_id, prop_id
FROM   site_prop;
```

This way you only need a single scan of table `sites` and neither window functions nor joins. Much cheaper.

#### Better yet

It would seem like a FK violation to insert rows with new `property_id` into `site_properties` while the key does not exist in `properties`, yet. But that's not the case if you insert the keys into `properties` in the **same command**. CTEs are considered part of the same command. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html)

> A constraint that is not deferrable will be checked immediately after
> every command.

So we can simplify some more, using `next_val()` and the `RETURNING` clause:

```
WITH site_prop AS (
   INSERT INTO site_properties (site_id, property_id)
   SELECT site_id
        , nextval(pg_get_serial_sequence('properties', 'property_id'))
   FROM   sites
   RETURNING site_id, property_id
   )
INSERT INTO properties (property_id, property_def_id)
SELECT property_id, 1
FROM   site_prop;
```

Related:

- [PostgreSQL next value of the sequences?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13394177/939860)
- [Inserting into related tables](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/89451/inserting-into-related-tables/89458#89458)

Answer (score 3):

It took me an awfully long while to figure it out, but here it goes:

Setup:

```
CREATE TABLE sites
(
  site_id INT PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE properties
(
  property_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  property_def_id INT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE site_properties
(
  property_id INT NOT NULL,
  site_id INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (property_id, site_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (property_id) REFERENCES properties(property_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (site_id) REFERENCES sites(site_id)
);

INSERT INTO sites VALUES (101),(102),(103);

INSERT INTO properties(property_def_id) VALUES (3), (4);
INSERT INTO site_properties(property_id, site_id) VALUES (1, 101), (2, 101);
```

Actual query:

```
WITH props AS (
  INSERT INTO properties (property_def_id)
    SELECT 1 FROM sites
  RETURNING property_id
), new_props AS (
  SELECT row_number() OVER () AS row, property_id
    FROM props
), all_sites AS (
  SELECT row_number() OVER () AS row, site_id
    FROM sites
)
INSERT INTO site_properties (site_id, property_id)
SELECT s.site_id, np.property_id
FROM all_sites s
  JOIN new_props np USING (row)
;
```

Checking everything works as expected:

```
SELECT *
FROM site_properties
  JOIN properties USING (property_id);


property_id | site_id | property_def_id
---------------------------------------
     1          101            3
     2          101            4
     3          101            1
     4          102            1
     5          103            1
```

Comment: This works, but there is a cheaper way.