# For each row create a linked row in another table with auto-generated ID

Tags: postgresql, insert, auto-increment, sequence, referential-integrity

In Postgres, I have an existing table:

`things`

| thing_id | thing_name | destination_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | thing 10 | null |
| 15 | thing 15 | null |

For each row in that table, I want to add rows to two new related tables one of which has an auto-generated ID. I then want to update rows in the old table to point to related new rows.

Desired result:

`things`

| thing_id | thing_name | destination_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | thing 10 | 1 |
| 15 | thing 15 | 2 |

`parent_destination`

| destination_id |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |

`child_destination`

| destination_id | destination_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [destination] thing 10 |
| 2 | [destination] thing 15 |

I have tried to do it here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6iyvCT7BYXPHPi2N2HvNor/1
but I can't work out how to return the correct data from `result1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with the `UPDATE` and fetch serial IDs for `parent_destination` from the underlying sequence with [`nextval()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-sequence.html) and [`pg_get_serial_sequence()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-CATALOG-TABLE). Then you have the needed connection to the `things` table, and the rest is simple:

```
WITH upd AS (
   UPDATE things t
   SET    destination_id = nextval(pg_get_serial_sequence('things', 'thing_id'))
   RETURNING thing_id, thing_name, destination_id
   )
, ins_parent AS (   
   INSERT INTO parent_destination(destination_id)
   SELECT destination_id
   FROM   upd
   )
INSERT INTO child_destination(destination_id, destination_name)
SELECT destination_id, concat('[thing]', thing_name)
FROM   upd;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/RET99G_a)

Related:

- [INSERT rows in two tables preserving connection to a third table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/160674/insert-rows-in-two-tables-preserving-connection-to-a-third-table/160825#160825)
- [Insert data in 3 tables at a time using Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20561627/939860)

The FK constraint is not violated while we do all of it in a single command. See:

- [Constraint defined DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE is still DEFERRED?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10035119/939860)

Comment: That's much nicer than my solution, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I worked out a way:

```sql
with result1 as (
    insert into parent_destination select from things returning destination_id
), result2 as (
    select destination_id, thing_id, thing_name
    from
    (select row_number() over (order by destination_id) as join_column, destination_id from result1) did
    join
    (select row_number() over (order by thing_id) as join_column, thing_id, thing_name from things) ts
    on did.join_column = ts.join_column
), result3 as (
    insert into child_destination(destination_id, destination_name) select destination_id, thing_name from result2
)
update things t
set destination_id = t2.destination_id
from result2 t2
where t1.thing_id = t2.thing_id;
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6iyvCT7BYXPHPi2N2HvNor/3