# What is the optimal pipeline for updating table on FK value in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

Hi I have the following schema in my app.

```
-- Table: Investment_round
CREATE TABLE Investment_round (
    id serial  NOT NULL,
    round_type varchar(50)  NOT NULL,
    money bigint  NOT NULL,
    Project_id int  NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT Investment_round_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

-- Table: Investor
CREATE TABLE Investor (
    id serial  NOT NULL,
    name int  NOT NULL,
    url int  NULL,
    Investment_round_id int  NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT Investor_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

-- Reference: Investment_round_startups_page (table: Investment_round)
ALTER TABLE Investment_round ADD CONSTRAINT Investment_round_startups_page
    FOREIGN KEY (Project_id)
    REFERENCES startups_page (angel_id)  
    NOT DEFERRABLE 
    INITIALLY IMMEDIATE
;

-- Reference: Investor_Investment_round (table: Investor)
ALTER TABLE Investor ADD CONSTRAINT Investor_Investment_round
    FOREIGN KEY (Investment_round_id)
    REFERENCES Investment_round (id)  
    NOT DEFERRABLE 
    INITIALLY IMMEDIATE
;
```

I'm a bit confused about optimal pipeline of inserting the data. Suppose that firstly I need to insert the data to `Investment_round` table. 
Then I need to insert the data to `Investor` table with corresponding `Investment_round_id`

It seems that the reasonable way is to store `Investment_round_id` and then to update `Investor` table. But how can I achieve that without making an external request?

Comment: You can insert into both tables in one statement in Postgres. See a similar question: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46410/how-do-i-insert-a-row-which-contains-a-foreign-key/46415#46415

Comment: How can I do it? Could you elaborate, please?

Comment: Sorry, this is a better example: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/89451/inserting-into-related-tables/89458#89458

Comment: ANd this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22775109/postgresql-multi-insert-returning-with-multiple-columns/22775268#22775268